# Android WebRTC on LAN - How can I specify a custom port range?

Tags: android, tcp, udp, webrtc, port

I am working on an Android WebRTC-based chat application, to be deployed onto my company's infrastructure.

To comply with our network policy, the UDP/TCP ports used by WebRTC should be restricted to a given range. I saw that the JNI side of the Android API provides this ability. All I would have to do would be to create my own subclass of **BasicPortAllocator** with my implementation of **min_port()** and **max_port()**.

However, I would like to know if this port range can be specified directly from the Java API using one of the **PeerConnectionFactory**'s configuration objects (such as **RTCConfiguration**). It is possible?

Thank you!